# Multiple VMs under VBox, NAT mode, are not responding network requests

Tags: networking, virtualization, nat, virtualbox

I am learning about virtualization. I have been managing real Linux servers for some time but this is the very first time I virtualize, so sorry if I am missing something.

My setup is like a small-company simulation: one firewall, one web server and one client (office). Everything is set up correctly, and all of them are working under NAT mode, according to VirtualBox.

Machine A: 192.168.1.1 (firewall, gateway) & vbox dhcp ip (for internet)
Machine B: 192.168.1.2 (gateway is Machine A)
Machine B: 192.168.1.3 (gateway is Machine A also)

Running all of them at the same time, I try to ping or access Machine B from C, or Machine A from B... but they're not communicating with each other, which is kind of strange, because they are sharing netmask, network and everything.

Left to say that firewall has been disabled and right now I am just trying with nothing as "protection", so it should be other kind of problem.

Any idea about what could be happening will be appreciated (maybe another networking mode would work for this?).

Thank you!

Comment: Get rid of that NAT-mode crap and go bridged. BTW, workstation virtualization is a lot different from what you would do with bare-metal hypervisors (ESXI,Xen, KVM, Hyper-V).   Most of which do not support NAT.

Comment: If you're just trying to "learn" virtualization, workstation virutalization is alright... but for a business environment, use a business hypervisor, even for learning.  It's what you will (or better be) using for business purposes, so save yourself some time and effort and learn on the platform you plan to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a status-by-design situation.

In NAT mode, your VMs all have their own virtual router, and aren't supposed to be able to connect to each other.  If you want to communicate between the VMs, use a host-only or bridged networking mode.

Comment: So I was wrong with that point... I understand it now. Thank you very much!